# Can a PSU handle nanosecond power-outtages?

Tags: power-supply, power

My GPU has recently died, and I got to wounder why. I have been having PC shutdowns and bluescreens over the last 5 years. I noticed at some point, that these often happen when someone turned on a light outside my room. I would hear the sound of the switch, then my PC would make a small sound (maybe like a HDD stopping to spin) and the system would be frozen to then bluecreen.

Over time this must have destroyed my GPU, and possibly other components over the years.

Can modern PSUs handle small surges or power cuts (for mili or nanoseconds)? And if not, is there a way to protect my next system?

Comment: Long-term, I'd get the mains looked at. In many countries lighting & power are not on the same circuit, so shouldn't affect each other. There's the possibility the light switch is sparking & sending RFI which upsets the computer, rather than it being a power dip. [Never buy cheap light switches, they're not worth it ;)

Comment: Nanosecond? Definitely no. Milliseconds are unlikely. Experience with a workstation where the nearby elevator caused dips lasting 0.5 seconds caused only intermittent problems on a workstation year ago. Any halfway decent ups will alleviate any doubts.

Comment: @doneal24 - an elevator, perhaps, but if a light bulb can cause a voltage dip there are far bigger problems in the household electricity supply.

Comment: @Tetsujin True but the light switch itself is not the cause of his problems.

Comment: @doneal24 - how do you know?

Comment: @Tetsujin If flipping a light switch with, at most, a few hundred watt load was damaging the PSU then other problems would manifest. Lights dimming when a computer or a vacuum turning on. Breakers turning off when major appliances draw load, etc. Since the OP did not mention this I am assuming he it not seeing those problems.

Comment: …which makes the switch itself *more* likely to be the problem, as I said in my fist comment. [btw, how many people do you know with 'a few hundred watts' of lighting these days?

Comment: @Tetsujin Unfortunately, there are way too many households in the US still using incandescent bulbs or floodlights. The requirement to not sell incandescents was derided as a government conspiracy to take away our rights. And I agree with RFI, not a power dip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that almost every electronic device should have is a surge protector such as this.

[image]

Every time something is turned on and off, it can produce a surge on the power line.  However, I think your problem is a bit more that the power actually dips.

You should have an Uninterruptible Power Supply (UPS). Here is a simple one for voltage fluctuations only

[image]

Here's a full-blown one that will handle brownouts too, for several minutes

[image]

Comment: I think it's more likely to be RFI than a power surge, tbh.